# Combining more than two charts in xlsx writer, using python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Here are my three chart types:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
area = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'area'})
scatter = workbook.add_chart({'type':'scatter'})
```

Expected output is to combine all 3 to put into a single graph:

```
chart.combine(area)     ##1 works fine
chart.combine(scatter)  ##if more than 2 combines; it picks only last one, ignores first combine
```

Example graph:

[image]

This currently has scatter and line merged, but I'd also like to merge area (or add an area fill) between the red line and the x axis (where x = 0) , to be able to see the difference between positive and negative. Thanks